# How to Fill area under a line plot depending on constraints

Tags: matplotlib, plot, fill

I have a plot, and some constraints. And basically, I want to fill an area under a fct line depending on those constraints. How can I do that ? With hatching as a patern if possible
The plot is a basic sin(x) graph, but let say my constraints are :

> ```
> -0.25 <= x <= 0.5
> 0 <= y <= 5
> ```

and the code is

```
 fig = plt.figure()
 ax = plt.axes()
    
 x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
 ax.plot(x, np.sin(x));
```

from what I read, I have to use

> plt.fill_between

But I don't understand how to use it

Answer (score 0):

Use [`fillbetween`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html?highlight=fill_between#matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between) and set the `y` constraint using [`np.minmum`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.maximum.html#numpy.minimum) and the `y2` parameter (default is `0`) and the `x` constraint using [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html?highlight=where#numpy.where).

Example hatch under curve, maximum up to y = 0.7 and x up to 1.0:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.linspace(0, 10, 1000)
plt.plot(x, np.sin(x))
plt.fill_between(x, np.minimum(np.sin(x), 0.7), where=x<=2, hatch='++', fc='w')
```

[image]